# Lenovo X230 and W530 won't install Windows Updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, thinkpad

It goes all the way through downloading all the updates, and when it gets mostly done installing it says there was an "Error-Could not install updates".

This is a brand new out of the box Lenovo X230 with nothing installed or configured. Everything is default.

This also applies to a Lenovo W530 as of 5/17/13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time (8/27/12) you have to install update KB2647753 first and ONLY by itself. Don't install others at the same time. Then restart, then do Windows Update as normal.

This also applies to a Lenovo W530 as of 5/17/13.

Comment: Any supporting links?